# Applying a constant force on pendulum and integrating for velocity

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

We apply a constant horizontal force $ F $ to a weight that's connected to a solid rod. I'd like to find out the velocity of the weight when it's at its horizontal position. See image below.
[image]

My attempt at solving it:

$$ {dv\over dt} = {F(\theta) \over m} $$
$$ {dv\over ds}{ds\over dt} = {F(\theta) \over m} $$
$$ {dv}{ds\over dt} = {F(\theta) \over m} ds $$
$$ {dv}\cdot v = {r \over m} F(\theta) d\theta $$
$$ {dv}\cdot v = {rF \over m} \cos(\theta) d\theta $$

Solving the integral I get

$$ {v^2 \over 2} = {rF \over m} \sin(\pi/2) = {rF \over m} $$

I'm pretty sure I messed up somewhere because this give's the wrong answer.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I just realized I didn't take into account $ g $ that's working against us!

Comment: Do you have to solve it with calculus? There is a far simpler way.

Comment: I don't. But I figured it would be good practice. I'd love to hear the alternative way (I think it involves energy, correct?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work done by $F$ is $rF$

Work done by gravity is $-mgr$

Kinetic energy of the mass is $1/2 m v^2$

$$rF-mgr=\frac12 m v^2$$

Comment: Thanks! Could you perhaps explain the reasoning behind work done by F? I don't follow how it equals rF.

Comment: Work is (distance in the direction of the force)*force. You need the projection of the distance onto the direction of your force.

Comment: Gotcha! Gonna wait a bit and see if someone can provide a calculus solution as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the $mgL$ term in your setup. It should be
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{F\cos\theta}{m}-g\sin\theta$$

Then do the same thing you will get the same answer as the one mentioned by grdgfgr.